# Laravel 5 mail not working Swift_RfcComplianceException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, swiftmailer

I am new to using laravel 5 and trying to send mail but I am getting the following.  error: `Swift_RfcComplianceException in MailboxHeader.php line 348:
Address in mailbox given [Kathmandu-Nepal] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.`

My code for the controller  is

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers\BackEnd;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Input;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Mail;

class MailController extends Controller {


    /**
     * Sends Mail.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function sendMail()
    {
        $user = Input::all();


        Mail::send('emails.simpleMail', $user, function($message)
        {
            $message->to(Input::get('emailto'))->subject('Simple Mail!');
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: the error is telling you what's the problem: "Kathmandu-Nepal" is not an email address.. you might be overwriting the email address with a location in your form (by using the same input name, for example)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem and the problem was that i have an invalid emailaddress in the mail configuration in \app\config\mail.php. So please check your configuration.

in my case the configuration contains something like:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Global "From" Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
| the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
| used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
|
*/

'from' => ['address' => 'null', 'name' => 'Your Name'],
```

i fixed it by setting a valid email address:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Global "From" Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
| the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
| used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
|
*/

'from' => ['address' => 'me@example.com', 'name' => 'Your name'],
```

Comment: @surajmishra Maybe you have a wrong, none rfc 2822 compilant e-mail address elsewhere in your script? For example, in your recipient's address?